# How do I access bucket object audio file through lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, speech-recognition

I am implementing aws lambda function that gets triggered by aws `s3 PUT` object created event.This lambda function is a Python speech recognizer that will get an audio upload object from the bucket(s3 PUT/upload event) and convert it into a text file, then put the data on dynamoDB, along with creating SNS message notification so that next lambda function can retrieve the message and id with corresponding data.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import boto3
import os
import uuid
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
r = sr.Recognizer() 
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    record_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+bucket)
    region = event['Records'][0]['awsRegion']
    logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+region)
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'] 
    logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+key)

    # download_path = os.path.join('tmp/',key)
    audio_fl = key
    logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+audio_fl)
    logger.info("start")


    with sr.AudioFile(audio_fl) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
    try:
      text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
      text = "UnknownValueError"
    except sr.RequestError as e:
      text = "RequestError"



    #Creating new record in DynamoDB table
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['DB_TABLE_NAME'])
    table.put_item(
        TextConversionProcess={
            "processID": record_id,
            "processName": "PythonSpeechRecognition",
            "processType": "SpeechRecognition",
            "processInput": audio_fl,
            "processOutput": text
            }
    )

    #Sending notification about new upload event to SNS
    client = boto3.client('sns')
    client.publish(
        TopicArn = os.environ['SNS_TOPIC'],
        Message = record_id
    )

    return record_id
```

My bucket `bucket_name` has an object, `object` which has audio file `audio.wav`.However, I'm getting `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'object/audio.wav': IOError`. This file does exist but I'm still getting IO error. Can someone help me?Please note that I'm new in aws python lambda.
The following is an output of a test event:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/python_transcription.py",
      27,
      "lambda_handler",
      "with sr.AudioFile(audio_fl) as source:"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/speech_recognition/__init__.py",
      203,
      "__enter__",
      "self.audio_reader = wave.open(self.filename_or_fileobject, \"rb\")"
    ],
    [
      "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wave.py",
      511,
      "open",
      "return Wave_read(f)"
    ],
    [
      "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wave.py",
      160,
      "__init__",
      "f = __builtin__.open(f, 'rb')"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "IOError",
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'csb-motus/recordings/ceo_audio_1.wav'"
}
```

bucket name: `csb-motus`
object name: `recordings`
file inside object: `audio-file.wav`

Comment: can you include output of a sample `event`.

Comment: @MadhukarMohanraju please see edit and thanks for reaching out.

Comment: You are not actually ever downloading this file from S3.  You're just taking `key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']` and then using `key` as though it were a file path, and trying to read it from the current working directory, which is probably `/var/task/`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the s3 PUT event already uploads file in recordings directory so I'm trying to get the key as file path and then read it.Is this wrong?

Comment: @Apples S3 PUT operation uploads the media file to S3. This triggers the lambda function and when you are processing the file(ie. converting media to speech), you must `GET` the media content and then pass it to speech synthesizer. See if you can use the `get_object()` method of boto3. You might also need to specify `response-content-encoding` and `response-content-type` in the request as this is a `.wav` file. Then store the data from the response into `audio_fl` and pass it to `sr.AudioFile(audio_fl)`.

Comment: Yes, @Apples, that is wrong.  What you have here is a only a notification that an object has been stored in a bucket. Objects in buckets are not the same thing as files on disks.  You are processing your notification in a Lambda container, which has ~512 MiB of temporary space for your use, at `/tmp`... but the object in the bucket is not accessible to you from here as a file.  If you need access to the object as a file, you need to do an S3 get-object to fetch it, save it in `/tmp`, then process it, then finally you need to delete it from inside `/tmp` when done.

Comment: Yes, @Michael-sqlbot is correct. You have to download the file from S3.